# WebDriverException: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH even though it is

Tags: macos, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Trying to get firefox to run using selenium in spyder. My current code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += ":/usr/local/bin/geckodriver"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

and I still get this error:

```
runfile('/Users/mherl/Dropbox/AnacondaProjects/MWS/MWSSpyder/test.py', 
wdir='/Users/mherl/Dropbox/AnacondaProjects/MWS/MWSSpyder')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-3f3f96ccf515>", line 1, in <module>

runfile('/Users/mherl/Dropbox/AnacondaProjects/MWS/MWSSpyder/test.py', 
wdir='/Users/mherl/Dropbox/AnacondaProjects/MWS/MWSSpyder')

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
  packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
  execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
  packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/mherl/Dropbox/AnacondaProjects/MWS/MWSSpyder/test.py", 
line 12, in <module>
  browser = webdriver.Firefox()

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 152, in 
__init__
self.service.start()

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)

WebDriverException: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Even though gekodriver is in that folder.

[image: proof that gekodriver is in the right place]

I have also tried exporting the path to ~./bash_profile which looks like this right now.

```
Last login: Fri Apr 20 10:57:16 on ttys000
dhcp-54-85:~ mherl$ nano ./bash_profile
dhcp-54-85:~ mherl$ nano .bash_profile
  GNU nano 2.0.6             File: .bash_profile                      
Modified  


# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda3 5.1.0 installer
export PATH="/Applications/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

#added by mherl to show path to gekodriver
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/gekodriver
```

I also have the current paths set in spyder:

```
/usr/local/bin
/Users/mherl/Dropbox/AnacondaProjects/MWS/MWSSpyder
```

of which gekodriver is in

```
/usr/local/bin
```

I have looked everywhere and most people say it should run automatically if it's in /usr/local/bin but it still can't seem to find it even when I explicitly state the path.

This is a mac running High Sierra if that's important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

...implies that the *GeckoDriver* wasn't found in the expected default location.

### Solution

As you are using *MAC based System* you need to pass the *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* referring to the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
```

### Additional Consideration

Ensure the following :

- GeckoDriver is present in the specified location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Execute your @Test as a non-root user.

Comment: This did work, but what is it about macOS that requires you to do it this way?

Comment: @MakennaSophiaHerl Not only macOS but each os behaves almost similar.

Comment: adding the executable_path argument worked for me on ubuntu(&pycharm) also !
Thanks a ton @DebanjanB, i was going crazy why it was not running when i could see the vale of my PATH environment variable was correct ! :)

Comment: I am running linux manjaro. Is geckodriver something that I should have by default or do I need to download it? Any hints as to where I could find it on my system? I found a geckodriver.log file (which was empty when i opened it)