# Error: The geckodriver executable could not be found on the current PATH on Mac using Node.js

Tags: node.js, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm doing a tutorial for selenium using node.js on MacOS but when I try to open Firefox I get the error:

```
Error: The geckodriver executable could not be found on the current PATH.
```

I'm at a loss at trying to implement the executable path using node.js. I have been guided to look at

[WebDriverException: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH even though it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947694/webdriverexception-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path-even-though-it)

I have looked at other examples but I am still confused on what I should do for node.js.

This is the path I'm trying to use:

```
/Users/myName/Documents/seleniumWebdrivers/geckodriver
```

How can I fix this?